# Is there a way to log user's basic info in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-events

I want to setup Facebook Advanced Matching in Flutter app so - I want to know if there a way to log user's basic info (name, email, phone, DOB, gender etc) with this package?

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events (Facebook App Events)

In `lib/facebook_app_events.dart` ([link](https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/blob/develop/lib/facebook_app_events.dart)) I see method to `clearUserData` method to clear user's data but don't see method to set these values.

Reference for setting up advanced matching on native app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/advanced-matching#use-the-facebook-sdk

Edit 1: To be clear I already have user's info and want to log it with Facebook.

Comment: Is the question about setting user data you already have, or about getting that user data in the first place? Because the latter would certainly not be the job of a package used to send app events.

Comment: @CBroe yes, setting user data we already have.

Comment: You could use a package like sharedpreferences (for simple data) or sqflite (for more complex data) to store data across sessions.

Comment: @JahnE. This is not about storing data locally but logging the user's information for analytics purpose with Facebook Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for spotting the mistake. You brought to my attention that the `setUserData` was accidentally removed in version [`0.14.1`](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events/changelog#0141) of the Flutter plugin as the deprecation notes were misread.

It is added back in upcoming version of the plugin: https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/pull/204